# adding object to toolbox using ItemsControl class

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm using two classes as Toolbox derived from ItemsControl and ToolboxItem derived from ContnentControl

```
// Implements ItemsControl for ToolboxItems    
public class Toolbox : ItemsControl
{

    // Defines the ItemHeight and ItemWidth properties of
    // the WrapPanel used for this Toolbox
    public Size ItemSize
    {
        get { return itemSize; }
        set { itemSize = value; }
    }

    private Size itemSize = new Size(50, 50);

    // Creates or identifies the element that is used to display the given item.        
    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new ToolboxItem();
    }

    // Determines if the specified item is (or is eligible to be) its own container.        
    protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
    {
        return (item is ToolboxItem);
    }
}





// Represents a selectable item in the Toolbox/>.
public class ToolboxItem : ContentControl
{
    // caches the start point of the drag operation
    private Point? dragStartPoint = null;

    static ToolboxItem()
    {
        // set the key to reference the style for this control
        FrameworkElement.DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(ToolboxItem), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ToolboxItem)));
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreviewMouseDown(e);
        this.dragStartPoint = new Point?(e.GetPosition(this));
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        base.OnMouseMove(e);
        if (e.LeftButton != MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            this.dragStartPoint = null;

        if (this.dragStartPoint.HasValue)
        {
            // XamlWriter.Save() has limitations in exactly what is serialized,
            // see SDK documentation; short term solution only;
            string xamlString = XamlWriter.Save(this.Content);
            DragObject dataObject = new DragObject();
            dataObject.Xaml = xamlString;

            WrapPanel panel = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this) as WrapPanel;
            if (panel != null)
            {
                // desired size for DesignerCanvas is the stretched Toolbox item size
                double scale = 1.3;
                dataObject.DesiredSize = new Size(panel.ItemWidth * scale, panel.ItemHeight * scale);
            }

            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, dataObject, DragDropEffects.Copy);

            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}

// Wraps info of the dragged object into a class
public class DragObject
{
    // Xaml string that represents the serialized content
    public String Xaml { get; set; }

    // Defines width and height of the DesignerItem
    // when this DragObject is dropped on the DesignerCanvas
    public Size? DesiredSize { get; set; }
}

public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }


    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        DesignerItem ni = new DesignerItem();
        ni.AllowDrop = true;
        ni.ToolTip = "tooltip goes here";
        ni.Width = 100;
        ni.Height = 200;
        ni.Background = Brushes.Red;

        //somehow code should introduce the object shape as object. in the sample on codeproject it is reading shape information from xaml but I need to add it from code behind. 


        Toolbox tb = new Toolbox();
        tb.Items.Add(ni);
```

AddChild() method from ItemsControl must be the method to add a new object on a toolbox. However, when I instantiate an object from this class it does not give me this method. For simplicity I only want to add a rectangle shape on it this would allow me to to drag/drop it on canvas. So question is how I can add a Rectangle on toobox.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.
Amit

Solution:

```
var TheToolbar = ToolboxContainer.Content as Toolbox;

// Instantiate a ToolboxItem
ToolboxItem TheToolboxItem = new ToolboxItem();

Rectangle myRect = new Rectangle();
myRect.StrokeThickness = 1;
myRect.Stroke = some value for stroke;
myRect.Fill = some value for filling the object;
myRect.IsHitTestVisible = false;
//add to Toolbar
TheToolboxItem.Content= myRect;
TheToolbar.Items.Add(TheToolboxItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

AddChild() is a protected method ( = accessible only from itself or from an inherited class). Try to use a code like this instead:

```
Toolbox tb = new Toolbox();
tb.Items.Add(myNewItem);
```

After you instantiate your objects, you need to add them as children to your canvas/parent element.

```
myParentElement.Children.Add(tb);
```

If you're doing it, include it in your example code.

Comment: Yes I have tired that too but when I debug and watch the object I see some of the attribute are not valid.

Comment: @amitkohan, what do you mean by "not valid"?

Comment: OK, I did instantiate an object exactly as you have posted here. It runs fine but it doesn't add/show any thing to/on the toolbox. I think I need to define an object to take care of its presentation. Because this class is using an XAML file as input where it reads it from a <ResourceDirectory> where in there you can see a set of <Path> and <Style><Setter> elements are defined and creating different shapes and then get added to the toolbox. Please look at this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part4/DiagramDesignerPart4.zip)   Thank you!

Comment: I think if I could declare the shape of the object I'm adding on toolbox it would be displayed on toolbox.

Comment: @amitkohan, your code looks pretty much the same as in that tutorial you've provided link for. But, I can't see the code where you actually add your control to the canvas, nor where you specify its children. I suspect the problem will be somewhere there ;)

Comment: yes you are right so I just did edit the code I had posted yesterday. Please see it in above. Thanks!

Comment: @amitkohan, you're creating an instance of your Toolbox and its children, but you're not assigning to a canvas...

Comment: I'm not an expert but is the toolbar part of canvas? if so then what do you suggest? how can I assign it?  Thank you

Comment: @amitkohan, see the update answer :) You need to add the instantiated Toolbox control to the collection of controls of the parent element you want to assign it to.

Comment: I'm having problem with getting its parent, its value is a set of zeros .... If toolbox is a child to expander (placed in <Expander>) and and Expander itself is located in a StackPanel which is a child to canvas then how can I get ParentId of Canvas?

Comment: @amitkohan, then you don't have to add it to canvas, but instead just adding it to Expander's control collection should be enough. The point is, your control has to be added somewhere, so you can see it rendered. If you just create a control without adding it anywhere, wpf doesn't know that you want to render it.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong. If that is the case then `            Toolbox tb = new Toolbox();
tb.Items.Add(ni);` should do it since toolbox in inside of expander, yet nothing is display.  Thanks

Comment: @amitkohan, I don't see the code where you do expander.Children.Add(tb). If you have that code and expander is correctly placed and visible on your wpf, then you have an issue.

Comment: I tried expander1.Children.Add() but Children is not being displayed!

Comment: anyway if I have to add it I should it add it to toolbar since toolbar is the parent which will be holding toolbar item.

Comment: Solution is added to the end of source code in top just for future similar question. Thanks to all for your help and comments.